# TypeScript bindings for class not working?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a definition file, let's call it `someclass.d.ts` that looks more or less like this:

```js
declare class SomeClass {
    static write : {
        doThing(name: string) : string
    }

    static get : {
        doThing2(count: number): string
    }
}
```

This matches the actual class in `someclass.ts`

```js
export default class SomeClass {
    static write = {
        doThing(name) {
            return "foo1";
        }
    }

    static get = {
        doThing2(count) {
            return "foo2";
        }
    }
}
```

And then in my `mainThing.ts`, which actually uses the SomeClass:

```js
/// <reference types="./someclass" />
import SomeClass from './someclass.ts';
SomeClass.write.doThing("dummyexample");
```

If I mouseover doThing in `mainThing.ts`/`someclass.ts` in VSCode, it acts like everything is implicit any typed, which tells me I'm doing *something* wrong. I just don't know what.

I'm guessing that I'm doing the declaration wrong for those class member blocks, but I'm not sure what the correct way to do it is; trying to do `static write = {` seems to make it look for function bodies...

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

**Edit:** I am aware I am not required to have a separate definition file, but I want to do so in the name of readable code. The *real* signature for doThing looks more like

```js
doThing({ name, email, password, p4, p5, p6 }
    : { name: string, email: string, password: string, p4: string, p5: number, p6: string }) 
    : Type1<Type2<Type3>>
```

**Edit 2**: Additionally, SomeClass doesn't actually need to be a class... maybe TypeScript namespaces (or something else) would be more appropriate? I'm mostly just trying to organize a large number of utility methods in a way that isn't overwhelming. Everything is deliberately static for this reason; there's no point instantiating SomeClass when it doesn't have any state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.d.ts` declaration file is meant to type-annotate `.js` file, not `.ts` file.

I can see that you're trying to use the Java convention here. Thing is JS `class` is quite different to Java `class`. TS is designed for JS so it won't serve you the way you expect it to. Although you can use `.d.ts` with `.ts` file, the usage that involves `class` is very tedious, that it beats the purpose of readable code.

My suggestion to your problem is to use plain object instead of `class-static` couple, since JS `class` is really syntax sugar to object.

**someclass.d.ts**

```
declare interface SomeClass {
  write: {
    doThing(name: string): string;
  };

  get: {
    doThing2(count: number): string;
  };
}
```

**someclass.ts**

```
const SomeClass: SomeClass = {
  write: {
    doThing(name) {
      return "foo1";
    }
  },

  get: {
    doThing2(count) {
      return "foo2";
    }
  }
};

export default SomeClass;
```

**mainThing.ts**

```
import SomeClass from './someclass.ts';
SomeClass.write.doThing(1);
// [TS ERROR] Argument of type '1' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

---

**Side Note:**

I said earlier that usage involving `class` is tedious. Here's how to do it if you really want to use `class-static`:

**someclass.d.ts**

```
declare abstract class SomeAbstractClass {
  static write: {
    doThing(name: string): string;
  }
}
```

**someclass.ts**

```
export default class SomeClass extends SomeAbstractClass {
  static write = {
    // you still need to re-write the function signature in class impl
    doThing(name: string) {
      return "foo1";
    }

    // all it does is just to warn you when you accidentally write:
    doThing(name: number) { // ERROR: should be string not number
      return "foo1";
    }
  }
}
```

You cannot use `class SomeClass implements SomeClassInterface`, cus `implements` keyword only governs the instance side of class, not static side.

Comment: It's weird typescript will let you arbitrarily annotate .js files, but not .ts files. The intersection in something like Cypress.io is kinda funky - you can add custom Cypress commands in a .js file, and they show up in your .ts files. But if you rename that js file to .ts... nope! Inheriting from an Interface makes sense, but it just seems like a weird limitation.

Comment: Welcome to jsland. The whole ecosystem is built on top of loads of legacy and people solve problems by hitting the refresh button. I'd say TS team has done a great job to put together such a robust language extension. It ain't perfect but considering how lousy JS is, it's almost a miracle.